# 1 Dimensional Variational Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm trying to Build  a one-dimensional autoencoder. The majority of code source I have found so fare are from 2 dimensional images. The input of the model is a vector of length 16 I show here the first as example:

`[1.05279021e-05, 1.40189689e-02, 1.24412028e-02, ..., 5.50764204e-03, 4.43428922e-03, 4.26333722e-03],`

The code inspired from the following repository:
https://github.com/davidADSP/GDL_code/blob/master/models/VAE.py

is the following

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback, LearningRateScheduler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

#### CALLBACKS
class CustomCallback(Callback):
    
    def __init__(self, run_folder, print_every_n_batches, initial_epoch, vae):
        self.epoch = initial_epoch
        self.run_folder = run_folder
        self.print_every_n_batches = print_every_n_batches
        self.vae = vae

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):  
        if batch % self.print_every_n_batches == 0:
            z_new = np.random.normal(size = (1,self.vae.z_dim))
            reconst = self.vae.decoder.predict(np.array(z_new))[0].squeeze()

            filepath = os.path.join(self.run_folder, 'images', 'img_' + str(self.epoch).zfill(3) + '_' + str(batch) + '.jpg')
            if len(reconst.shape) == 2:
                plt.imsave(filepath, reconst, cmap='gray_r')
            else:
                plt.imsave(filepath, reconst)

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.epoch += 1



def step_decay_schedule(initial_lr, decay_factor=0.5, step_size=1):
    '''
    Wrapper function to create a LearningRateScheduler with step decay schedule.
    '''
    def schedule(epoch):
        new_lr = initial_lr * (decay_factor ** np.floor(epoch/step_size))
        
        return new_lr

    return LearningRateScheduler(schedule)
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint 
from keras.utils import plot_model

#from utils.callbacks import CustomCallback, step_decay_schedule 
"""
from tensorflow.keras import (
    layers,
    models,
    datasets,
    callbacks,
    losses,
    optimizers,
    metrics,
)
"""

import numpy as np
import json
import os
import keras
import pickle


class VariationalAutoencoder():
    def __init__(self
        , input_dim
        , encoder_dim_list
        , encoder_activation_function         
        , decoder_dim_list
        , decoder_activation_function                 
        , z_dim
        , use_batch_norm = False
        , use_dropout= False):

        self.name = 'variational_autoencoder'

        self.input_dim = input_dim
        
        self.encoder_dim_list= encoder_dim_list
        self.encoder_activation_function = encoder_activation_function 
        
        self.decoder_dim_list = decoder_dim_list
        self.decoder_activation_function = decoder_activation_function 
        
        self.z_dim = z_dim

        self.use_batch_norm = use_batch_norm
        self.use_dropout = use_dropout

        self.n_layers_encoder = len(encoder_dim_list)
        self.n_layers_decoder = len(decoder_dim_list)

        self._build()

    def _build(self):
        
        ### THE ENCODER
        encoder_input = Input(shape=self.input_dim, name='encoder_input')

        x = encoder_input

        for i in range(self.n_layers_encoder):
            dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(self.encoder_dim_list[i], 
                                       activation = self.encoder_activation_function,
                                       name = 'encoder_dense_' + str(i)) 
            
            x = dense_layer(x)

            if self.use_batch_norm:
                x = BatchNormalization()(x)

            if self.use_dropout:
                x = Dropout(rate = 0.25)(x)

        self.mu = Dense(self.z_dim, name='mu')(x)
        self.log_var = Dense(self.z_dim, name='log_var')(x)

        self.encoder_mu_log_var = Model(encoder_input, (self.mu, self.log_var))

        def sampling(args):
            mu, log_var = args
            epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu), mean=0., stddev=1.)
            return mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon

        encoder_output = Lambda(sampling, name='encoder_output')([self.mu, self.log_var])

        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoder_output)
        
        

        ### THE DECODER

        decoder_input = Input(shape=(self.z_dim,), name='decoder_input')

        #x = Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flattening))(decoder_input)
        #x = Reshape(shape_before_flattening)(x)
        x = decoder_input
        
        for i in range(self.n_layers_decoder):
            dense_layer =  keras.layers.Dense(self.decoder_dim_list[i], 
                                       activation = self.decoder_activation_function,
                                       name = 'decoder_dense_' + str(i)) 
            
    

            x =  dense_layer(x)

            if i < self.n_layers_decoder - 1:
                if self.use_batch_norm:
                    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
                #x = LeakyReLU()(x)
                if self.use_dropout:
                    x = Dropout(rate = 0.25)(x)

        decoder_output = x

        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output)

        ### THE FULL VAE
        model_input = encoder_input
        model_output = self.decoder(encoder_output)

        self.model = Model(model_input, model_output)


    def compile(self, learning_rate, r_loss_factor):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        ### COMPILATION
        def vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            r_loss = K.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2, axis=1)
            return r_loss_factor * r_loss

        def vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            kl_loss =  -0.5 * K.sum(1 + self.log_var - K.square(self.mu) - K.exp(self.log_var), axis = 1)
            return kl_loss

        def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            r_loss = vae_r_loss(y_true, y_pred)
            kl_loss = vae_kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
            return  r_loss + kl_loss

        optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = vae_loss,  metrics = [vae_r_loss, vae_kl_loss])

    """
    def save(self, folder):

        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, 'viz'))
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, 'weights'))
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, 'images'))

        with open(os.path.join(folder, 'params.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump([
                self.input_dim
                , self.encoder_conv_filters
                , self.encoder_conv_kernel_size
                , self.encoder_conv_strides
                , self.decoder_conv_t_filters
                , self.decoder_conv_t_kernel_size
                , self.decoder_conv_t_strides
                , self.z_dim
                , self.use_batch_norm
                , self.use_dropout
                ], f)

        self.plot_model(folder)\
        
    def load_weights(self, filepath):
        self.model.load_weights(filepath)
    """
                                    
    def train(self, x_train, batch_size, epochs, initial_epoch = 0, lr_decay = 1):

        #custom_callback = CustomCallback(run_folder, print_every_n_batches, initial_epoch, self)
        lr_sched = step_decay_schedule(initial_lr = self.learning_rate, decay_factor = lr_decay, step_size=1)
        
        #checkpoint_filepath=os.path.join(run_folder, "weights/weights-{epoch:03d}-{loss:.2f}.h5")
        #checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, save_weights_only = True, verbose=1)
        #checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(run_folder, 'weights/weights.h5'), save_weights_only = True, verbose=1)

        #callbacks_list = [checkpoint1, checkpoint2, custom_callback, lr_sched]
        callbacks_list = [lr_sched]

        self.model.fit(     
            x_train
            , x_train
            , batch_size = batch_size
            , shuffle = True
            , epochs = epochs
            , initial_epoch = initial_epoch
            , callbacks = callbacks_list)

INPUT_DIM = [16]

vae = VariationalAutoencoder(
                input_dim = INPUT_DIM
                , encoder_dim_list = [16, 12, 8, 4, 2]
                , encoder_activation_function = 'selu'
                , decoder_dim_list = [2, 4, 8, 12, 16]
                , decoder_activation_function = 'selu'
                , z_dim=2
                , use_batch_norm=False
                , use_dropout=False)
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005
R_LOSS_FACTOR = 10000
EPOCHS = 200
PRINT_EVERY_N_BATCHES = 100
INITIAL_EPOCH = 0  

vae.compile(LEARNING_RATE, R_LOSS_FACTOR)
vae.train(  train
            , batch_size = 10 
            , epochs = EPOCHS
            , initial_epoch = INITIAL_EPOCH)
```

Regrettably I get the following error:

> TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_2'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.

Can you provide any support?